# I want to call images and audio lists in order using AudioPlayer()

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, flame

I'm going to make an app that plays a list of images and audio in order. After audio playback, the following images and audio are played.
I update image to setState() when the playback is completed. And each time use `setState()`, I used `play()` function inside the `build()` method to recall `play()`.

However, the method in the build is called twice, so the audio file is also played twice.

How do I run this method only once when I build it?

```
class PlayingScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final PostModel postModel;

  PlayingScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.postModel,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<PlayingScreen> createState() => _PlayingScreenState();
}

class _PlayingScreenState extends State<PlayingScreen> {
  final _audioPlayer = AudioPlayer(); 
  List<String> _audios = []; // audio file path list
  int _playIndex = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _getAudios();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _audioPlayer.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    _play(_playIndex);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.postModel.title),
      ),
      body: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          Get.back();
        },

       // image widget
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Future _play(int index) async {
    await _audioPlayer.play(DeviceFileSource(_audios[index]));
    logger.d("current index: $_playIndex / ${_audios.length - 1}");
    //complete event
    _audioPlayer.onPlayerComplete.listen((event) {
      logger.d("complet, next");
      setState(() {
        if (_playIndex >= _imageSets.length - 1) {
          _playIndex = 0;
          logger.d("return first index");
        } else {
          _playIndex++;
        }
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// ...
int _playIndex = 0;
bool played = false
// ...

// build
if(! played) {    
  _play(_playIndex);
  played = true;
}
```

1. Add the variable "played" at the class level
2. Add a check in the build method

Comment: The code above solves your particular problem. The best solution is to call the _play() method in initState() @kevin-yang

Comment: I corrected my post because I thought my question was a little wrong. The method you told me is called only at the beginning, and after that, even if setState() is called, play() is not called. My play() has to repeat the image and audio list in order. The problem with my code was that build() ran twice(when setStsate()), and the recordings were played twice at a time. Could you tell me about this, too? Thank you. –

Answer (score 1):

Calling a future inside the build method will always rebuild multiple times not only twice.
I would probably use it in a `FutureBuilder()` like so:

```
FutureBuilder(
future:_play(_playIndex),
builder:(context, snapshot){
 ...
 }

)
```